# How to prove SO2(C) is subgroup of SU2(C)?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

A real orthogonal matrix is unitary. But is a complex orthogonal matrix unitary?  In other words, SO2 is subgroup of SU2 when the field is R. But does the result hold good when the field is C?

Comment: How would you define "complex orthogonal matrices" then?

Comment: When A'A= AA'=I ?

Comment: Taking only transpose

Answer (score 2):

No. A complex  matrix cannot satisfy $A^{-1}=A^T$ and $A^{-1}=A^H=\overline{A^T}$ *unless* its entries are all real.

For instance, $\begin{pmatrix}2&-i\sqrt3\\ i\sqrt3 &2\end{pmatrix}\in SO(2,\Bbb C)\setminus SO(2,\Bbb R)$, and therefore it cannot be an element of $SU(2)$. This can be used to find matrices in $SO(n,\Bbb C)\setminus SU(n)$ for all $n\ge2$.

Comment: Take the 2x2 matrix A where 1st row is i.   √2. Secind row is  - √2.   i. Here AA'= I. So A is orthogonal, but not unitary. Sorry I don't know to write in the matrix form on my keyboard.

Comment: So a complex matrix can be orthogonal without being real.

Comment: @HeerackGanguly The answer doesn't say that there are no complex matrices that are orthogonal; it only says that there are no complex matrices (i.e. with non-zero imaginary part) which are *both* orthogonal and unitary.

Comment: Ok. Got it now. But does it imply that SO2 over C can't be a subgroup of SU2 over C. I was trying to prove it on the line that a unitary matrix is orthogonal. Now I got that that is not true. So, does the proposition about subgroup here holds only when the field is R, not C?